# Can an iOS app invoke a shortcut created by the user?

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts

Can an iOS app access the list of shortcuts created by the user and run on of them? Of course, if this is possible, the user has to authorize the app. But I am not sure if the APIs even allow such behavior.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such API is available as of now.